# Pass client side js variable into server side jscript

Tags: variables, client-side, server-side, javascript

How can I get the query string from the browser url using client side js and set it as a variable to use in some server side scripting?

Client side script:

```
var project = getQueryString("P");

function getQueryString(param) {
    var queryString = window.location.search.substring(1);
    splitQueryString = queryString.split("&");

    for (i=0; i<splitQueryString.length; i++) {
        query = splitQueryString[i].split("=");
        if (query[i] == param) {
        return query[1];
        }
    }

}
```

Server side script:

```
response.write ('<td><a href="/index.asp?P=' + project + ">' + obj.BODY[i].NAME + '</a></td>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ASP I think you're looking for String(Request.queryString("P"))

You have to use the String constructor because the queryString method returns a collection.

Comment: This doesn't solve my actual question which can simply be answered as, 'not possible to do', but this does solve problem with the querystring.  For ASP I've found that Request.QueryString.Item("P") works better by allowing me to access the specific object in the collection as a string rather than converting it.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the jQuery plugin [getUrlParam](http://www.mathias-bank.de/2007/04/21/jquery-plugin-geturlparam-version-2/) to do this in the past. Worked pretty well.

```
var project = $(document).getUrlParam("P");
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking for a method that doesn't require using a js library if possible.

Comment: you could take a look at his plugin's code to see how it is done, then do it yourself without any dependencies on jQuery itself.

Comment: +1 for this because I have done the same thing in the past without relying on JQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can't set any variable in the client side to be used in a server-side script without passing the value to the server via some HTTP request (possibly XHR).  So maybe I am misunderstanding your question.

Server-side scripting is typically used to generate HTML that is sent to the client side, and the server-side script is therefore done executing *before* the client can do anything, not to mention the server is in a completely different memory space.

Server-side scripting could also *receive* data from the client side, but only by way of another HTTP request from the client, as mentioned above.

Comment: Perhaps I phrased my question wrong.  I know I can't set a variable client side to be used in server-side without passing, my question is how to pass that variable from client side to server (without actually submitting a form or anything that is).  I'm outputting several objects server side and would like to link them based on a param in the URL that I can only get client side.